# Creating a Ninject Kernel in Global.asax where a binding has a dependency on HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, global-asax, httpcontext

I keep getting an error "System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context" when creating my Kernel. Which makes sense given that one of my bindings has a dependency on the Context. Obviously no context should be present on Application_Start. I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to resolve this.

```
public class NinjectBindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {     
        //Framework
        Bind<IJsonLayer>().To<JsonLayer>();
        Bind<IBusinessLayer>().To<BusinessLayer>();

        //Controllers
        Bind<ITeamController>().To<TeamController>();
    }
}


public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReflectionUtility.Kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectBindings());
    }
}


public class ReflectionUtility
{
    private static IKernel _kernel;

    public static IKernel Kernel {
        set { _kernel = value; }
    }
}



public class JsonLayer : IJsonLayer
{
    private readonly ITeamController _teamController;
    private readonly IBusinessLayer _businessLayer;

    public JsonLayer(ITeamController teamController, IBusinessLayer businessLayer)
    {
        _teamController = teamController;
        _businessLayer = businessLayer;
    }
}


public class BusinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
{
    //this is a super-simplification of what's going on. there are multiple different calls to HttpContext.Current.Request in this class
    public BusinessLayer()
    {
         //This is where it breaks
         var sessionUserId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-SessionUserId"];
    }

}

public class TeamController : ITeamController
{
      public void DeleteTeam(int intTeam)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't make a dependency out of the `HttpContext`, just when you setup a variable to contain the injected service, I would then assign the `HttpContext` to a property. Only because it makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your think, that access to the `HttpContext` from `Business` layer is good idea? Maybe you can spend some time on refactoring? For example, something like [this](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

From application perspective you can do something like this:

```
private void RegisterDependencyResolver()
{
     kernel
     .Bind<ISession>()
     .To<SessionService>()
     .InRequestScope()
     .WithConstructorArgument(
         "context", 
         ninjectContext => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)
      );

     DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
}
```

Comment: not sure why this got downvoted, but this is the correct way to approach this problem. you do not want concrete dependencies in your business layer. create an abstraction!